# Password protect a column in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have encountered a problem that I need a hand with.

I have already done numerous searches of this forum and others to see if I could solve it that way but it appears I have come a cropper.

So here goes...

I have altered a public Google docs template to help me track a loan that I have borrowed from my parents, I have shared the doc with them so they can access it and view it without editing - I have managed to get it to do what I wish to do apart from one issue.

I wish to password protect a column that my parents can access with a password of there choice to confirm that I have paid that particular installment of the loan. I know you can name and protect columns but being the owner of the sheet I can still access this column. Is there any way I can do this and get my parents to set a password that I don't know so only they can access the Doc I have shared with them?

Perhaps JavaScript could be used?

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

It's not possible to block a range from be edited by the owner of the spreadsheet.

## Alternatives

1. Transfer the ownership of the file to one of your parents and let them set  protection for the columns.
2. Use another spreadsheet owned by one of your parents make them share it with you with view access and import the column using [IMPORTRANGE()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en). It's recommend that set a column to hold keys/ids for the records in order to prevent misplacing of the related data.

## References

[Protect a range or sheet from being edited - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/144687?hl=en)